Source of "there's nothing so whole as a broken heart"
I've often heard in the name of the Rebbi of Kotzk the expression "אין שלם מלב שבור" (there's nothing so whole as a broken heart). However, upon searching for the source of the expression, I was unable to find where the Rebbi may have written it, or at least find the person who first said it in his name. Does anyone know where the expression first appears? Was it really said by the Kotzker?

https://www.hidabroot.org/article/1199540.   אין שלם מלב שבור

Thanks for the correction, it was a late-night Freudian slip.

I have always seen it associated with the Kotsker Rebbe.  However, the Zohar has a similar expression:

There is no greater light than the light that comes out of the darkness... and no true good except the good that comes out of evil. [Zohar, Shemot 2, p184a]


There's a big difference between a lev nishbar and darkness/evil. Rebbe Nachman in the Sichos discusses how a lev nishbar is the best state a person can be in. That's a far cry from evil.

@Yehuda -- A broken heart is a form of darkness.  It's not evil, so the second part of the Zohar quote does not apply.

Sadness is a form of darkness. It's called marah shechorah. Brokenheartedness is very much not dark - לב נשבר ונדכה אלקים לא תבזה.
